# Explanation for matlab multidimensional indexing

Tags: matlab

Suppose  I create the following matrix M.

```
>>>M = reshape(linspace(11,18,8),[2, 2, 2])
>>>M(:,:,1) =

   11    13
   12    14


   M(:,:,2) =

   15    17
   16    18

>>>M([1,2],[2, 1],[2,1])

>>>   
   ans(:,:,1) =

   17    15
   18    16


   ans(:,:,2) =

   13    11
   14    12
```

Please explain how the command M([1,2],[2, 1],[2,1]) produces the above result.explain the indexing in detail.

Comment: In a 3d array matlab saves the sub matrices (or call them sub pages / layers) in the third dimension as you see it in your own example. So reading it from the back: You want the second and the first  Matrix, in this order (last [2,1]), of these matrices you want first the second column and then the first (middle[2,1]) and finally you want both rows in the order [1,2](first). This is why you get this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start with simple example,

`M([1,2],1,1)` is going to show rows 1 and 2 of column 1 and 2d matrix 1.

```
ans =

    11
    12
```

`M([2,1],1,1)` is going to exchange rows 1 and 2 of column 1 and 2d matrix 1.

```
ans =

    12
    11
```

So changing the first index changes the rows order. Similarly Modifying second index will change the column order. And modifying third index will change the 2d matrices order.
Now let us take small example before we go to your problem,

```
M([1,2],[2,1],1)
```

Will exchange the columns of both rows of first 2d matrix.

```
ans =

    13    11
    14    12
```

And  `M([1,2],[1,2],[2,1])` will exchange between 1st 2d matrix and the second,

```
ans(:,:,1) =

    15    17
    16    18


ans(:,:,2) =

    11    13
    12    14
```

So combining the last two examples will exchange the 2d matrices and exchange their columns with keeping the orders of rows and that what exactly your answer shows

```
M([1,2],[2, 1],[2,1])

ans(:,:,1) =

    17    15
    18    16


ans(:,:,2) =

    13    11
    14    12
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

First, `M` is a three-dimensional matrix, which consists of two 2x2 matrix. So `M(:,:,1)` will get the first 2x2 matrix, and `M(:,:,2)` will get the second 2x2 matrix.

Some examples :

`M(1, 2, 2)` will give answer `17`, which is the element in row `1` and column `2` of the 2nd matrix.

`M(1, 1, [2, 1])` will give answers : `15` and `11` in that order. It will gather the element in row `1` and column `1`, of each from the two matrix in `[2 1]` order (so it will return from the 2nd matrix first).

`M(1, 1, [1, 2])` will give answers : `11` and `15` in that order. It will gather the element in row `1` and column `1`, of each from the two matrix in `[1 2]` order (so it will return from the 1st matrix first).

`M(1, [1 2], [2, 1])` will give answers : `15 17` and `11 13` in that order. It will gather the element(s) in row `1` of column `1` & `2` (in this order), of each from the two matrix in `[2 1]` order (so it will return from the 2nd matrix first).

`M(2, [1 2], [2, 1])` will give answers : `16 18` and `12 14` in that order. It will gather the element(s) in row `2` of column `1` & `2` (in this order), of each from the two matrix in `[2 1]` order (so it will return from the 2nd matrix first).

`M(2, [1 1], [2, 1])` will give answers : `16 16` and `12 12` in that order. It will gather the element(s) in row `2` of column `1` & `1` (*same column), of each from the two matrix in `[2 1]` order (so it will return from the 2nd matrix first).

So,

`M([1 2], [2 1], [2, 1])` will give answers :

```
17 15 
18 16
```

( which means the output is a 2x2 matrix, with 1st column and 2nd column are 2nd column and 1st column (respectively, by `[2 1]`) of the 2nd matrix. The 1st row and 2nd row are 1st and 2nd rows (respectively, by `[1 2]`) of the 2nd matrix. )

and also

```
13 11
14 12
```

....

**Also, you may want to read the documentation :** https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html